# modificar codigo fuente java jsp sin codigo fuente

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, hibernate, java-ee

Buen dia a todos, actualmente existe una aplicacion hecha el java jsp  que esta alojado en un servidor funciona perfectamente pero se requiere cambiarla de servidor pero no existe codigo fuente solo el compilado que se encuentra en el servidor. EL problema es que se necesita cambiar nuevos datos de conexion para la base de datos. Quisiera saber como puedo solucionar este problema o algun programa que a partir del compilado me traiga el codigo fuente. Soy nuevo en java. Gracias a todos.

Comment: Depende de dónde esté configurada la conexión de la base de datos. Si el servidor tiene definido un *datasource* en context.xml, es posible que no tengas que cambiar nada en el WAR/EAR

Comment: existe un archivo que es de tipo xml llamado hibernate.cfg y tiene los datos de conexion. Cambiandolos por los actuales datos de conexion funcionaria?

Comment: Sí, debería funcionar

Comment: Luego de realizar los cambios a esos archivos, debere reiniciar tu servidor

Comment: no me funciono esta forma. tienes otra solucion